# Diagonalizable matrix inspection from its row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have a question regarding when a matrix is diagonalizable

Suppose we have a $n \times n$ matrix $A$. Let's say that I row reduce and I find the matrix $B$, which is the row echelon form of the initial matrix $A$. If $B$ has zero rows only in the end, meaning it is of the following form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a11 & a12 & a13 & \dots\\0 & a22 & a23 & \dots\\ 0 & 0 & a33 & \dots \\\vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\end{bmatrix}
$$

can we say that matrix $A$ is diagonalizable? If yes, then I want to ask another question. Suppose that I row reduce matrix $A$ and zero rows occur in "random" positions in the matrix(meaning that zero rows are not in the end). Is it possible to create another matrix $C$ with the same rows with $A$ but in different order, such that $C$ has the appropriate row echelon form and, hence, for it to be diagonalizable?

Comment: No, you cannot say the original matrix is diagonalizable. You can't say the original matrix is diagonalizable on the basis of it row echelon form at all. For example, the identity is definitely diagonalizable, but $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)$ is not, but they are both row echelon forms of each other. The fact that you have rows of zeros tells you that the matrix is less than full rank, which means $0$ is an eigenvalue, but in general you won't be able to say much more than what its algebraic multiplicity is.

Comment: Note that elementary row operations do *not* preserve the characteristic polynomial, so there is no good reason to think that diagonalizability would be preserved. Note also that a row echelon form (even a reduced row echelon form) is not unique, so you should not talk about **the** row echelon form of $A$; there may be more than one.